# Puppeteer - how to click on an inner element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm using Puppeteer to do e2e tests for an app built with React and Material-UI.

In my login form I'm trying to click on the login button but I get `loginBtn.click is not a function` - that's because Material UI (version 0.21.0) is wrapping the `<RaisedButton>` with an extra div so I can only reach the outer element. I need a way to access the inner element and then simulate the click event.

I've tried this:

```js
const loginBtn = await page.$eval(
    '.login-form-button', 
    (element) => element.innerHTML
);
await loginBtn.click();
```

But it seems like `element.innerHTML` is just a text and not clickable.

Any ideas how can I get the inner element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`page.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) selects an element (`.login-form-button`) and passes that element to the second argument (`(element) => element.innerHTML`), which will in your case return the HTML of the node as a string. Therefore `loginBtn` is not a button but a string. To click an element you might want to use [page.click](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options).

If you have a more complex term to execute I recommend using [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). In your case you could use it like this to query the element and click its first child element:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.login-form-button').firstElementChild.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I took a different approach and use this solution using xpath:  
`await page.$x(\`//button[contains(., '${text}')]\`);`.